# Django logout is not logging out user

Tags: django, django-views, logout

I have done a lot of searching and all I can really find are variants of the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    # Redirect to a success page.
```

Here is the code from my view:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def leave(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect("index")
```

However, it neither logs the user out nor goes to the index page.

I also have:

```
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

in my urls page. I tried prefixing my urls with "accounts/" but that just resulted in errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your settings.py add this

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
```

in your template if you want to log out a user just call this (href="{% url 'logout' %}") something like this

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'logout' %}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> log out</a>
```